# How to create a second posts page which client can update

Tags: posts

Bit of a wordpress novice and so just wanted to know the best way to do this.

I am currently creating a wordpress site for a client. They have a Latest News section which is the primary 'blog'/posts page. The sidebar also displays the latest blog post.

Now what I would like to do is create a Special Offers page, which works the same as the blog post page, displaying the latest offers, and which the client can update easily through the admin. I would also like to feature the latest special offer in the sidebar.

What would be the best way to do this, as I am assuming you can only have one main posts page?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try Using [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) ! This will enable to create a different section in your admin area and it'll work same as normal blog post. Read the codex to know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect case for [custom post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

Simply create a post type called "specials" and you can use it just like your regular posts.

EDIT:
If you're new to WordPress and aren't interested in editing PHP, you can use a plugin like the [Custom Post Type UI](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/)